# Why I can't fetch responses from aiohttp in cycle? Exception: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file + aiohttp.payload.LookupError

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

When I tried to get response from each api_key in cycle I'm always confused with two errors - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file AND aiohttp.payload.LookupError...

```
async def get_api_response(photo_bytes, api_key, language):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(URL_API,
                                data={
                                    "picture.png": photo_bytes,
                                    "apikey": api_key,
                                    "language": language
                                }) as response:
            return await response.text()
```

It`s async function for async requests to API

```
for api_key in API_KEYS:
    response = json.loads(await get_api_response(photo_bytes=photo_bytes, api_key=api_key, language=photo_lang))
    print(response)
```

And this is cycle with results ↑

But when I tried to implement cycle in the function - gives the same result. But when I call function without cycle - it's work!
How can this be fixed with minimal changes?

**UPD: DURING RESEARCH I'M NOTICED THAT IT'S OCCURES WHEN AFTER FIRST CYCLE PHOTO_BYTES CLOSE UP**.

Here is init photo_bytes:

```
photo = cv2.imread(photo_path)
unused_var, compressed_image = cv2.imencode('.png', photo, [1, 90])
photo_bytes = io.BytesIO(compressed_image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like something like this

```
with io.BytesIO(compressed_image) as f:
    photo_bytes = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in which I pass one `BytesIO` object to multiple request.

The problem seem to be that aiohttp closes the `BytesIO` object when it finished using it, so we can't reuse it with another request.

The solution is to create `BytesIO` object every time I pass it to request method.